# Facebook Check IsFan is not working, please help

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '197724456937488', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

            // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {

         document.getElementById('likepost').style.display = "";
             document.getElementById('falsebox').style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById('fb').style.display = "";

});

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
    console.log('This was UNliked from this page: ' + window.location);
});
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

    </script>

    <div id="fb" style="display:none">    
    <fb:like-box href="<?php echo $detail['Post_FB'] ;?>" width="292" height="100" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
    </div>
    <div id="link" style="display:none">
    <fb:like href="http://design-pro.co.cc/appleworld/post.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your starting point for reference:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

First thing to notice is how FB.init() call is wrapped in:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  ...
};
```

You are already setting 'status' to true in your init call, so you should be able to subscribe to an event which will return the status value, which tells you the user's login status.

Check out:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Your `FB.Event.subscribe(...)` call should also be inside the same `window.fbAsyncInit()` call.

Once you verify that user is logged in, you can check for fan status.  You still have to use the old REST API, since Facebook hasn't ported this over to Graph API:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/

> Please note: We are in the process of
>   deprecating the REST API, and will be
>   adding equivalent support to the Graph
>   API for this method. You should
>   continue to use this method until we
>   announce support in the Graph API.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

This tutorial might also help: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks. i have modified the code, it can detect isfan correctly on some facebook account, but some of my friends facebook account returned "isfans" even they didn't like the page. Do you know why?